# How to design a Relational Data Base to store quiz and its related components and also to store user responses for that quiz system?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

A quiz system which has title,description,array of question sections(aptitude,reasoning etc..) where question section again contains title, description, array of questions with input text boxes, radio buttons(if question is an MCQ), check box(if question has multiple answers), also a dynamic array of file upload.

Can anyone help me designing a relational database to the above quiz system?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To start, you want to identify all the distinct entity types in your system. From your question text, the following entities jump out to me:

Quiz
Question
Answer_Option (a single multiple choice possible answer, for example)

Your database design would have a table for each of the three entities listed above.

Some of the elements you listed would be considered properties of the entities listed above. For example, the "Quiz" entity has a property of "title" and "description." Title and description will become columns in your "Quiz" table.

The relationships between these entities will likely be one to many, unless you would like questions to be shared between different quizzes. For example, there will be a foreign key column in the "Questions" table that references the unique id of the Quiz that the question belongs to. The same would be true for "Answer_Option" and "Question."

For the "Question" table, you could have a column that represents the question type (MCQ, text box, file upload, etc). This would provide information to your UI regarding how to display the question.

In general, you need to clearly define your entities and determine which attributes belong to which entities. Once this has been decided, you can create a table for each entity, and a column in the table for each of that entity's attributes. Foreign keys will be used to resolve the relationships between the entities.